# What would happen if the Hutt Clans had joined the Separatists?

Tags: star-wars, jabba-the-hutt

In the Clone Wars movie, the Republic does its best to ensure Jabba the Hutt allow the Republic safe passages through its territory.  But how much difference would it have made if Jabba had instead joined the separatists?

Was there any in-universe or word-of-God discussion of the possible consequences?  Was it believed that this one incident was likely to tip the balance of the war?

Comment: That's a discussion question. We really don't do those, although we do have a chat room once you have sufficient reputation, which you can get by answering a few questions, good edits, or the like.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - It seems pretty answerable.

Comment: @Valorum - Obviously, the Hutts would have pretended to work with the Republic, and betrayed them to the Separatists as often as possible while maintaining plausible deniability. Well, at least, that's *my* opinion....

Comment: Maybe it could be rephrased to something like "Were the Hutts joining either side expected to tip the balance of power in the Clone Wars?" That seems less opinion based and more objective, yet still preserves what the author is intending.

Comment: Hi pikppa and welcome to Stack Exchange!  I have edited your question to be more clearly in line with the Science Fiction and Fantasy site rules.  If you don't like the changes I've made, you can roll them back (by clicking on the "edited x minutes ago" link) or make further changes (by clicking on the "edit" link).

Answer (score 10):

The Clone Wars [Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(novels)) furnishes us with the judgement of five different men (of varying ranks and positions) regarding the ***likely*** consequences of the Hutt having offered tacit support to one side or the other.

**All seem to be in broad(ish) agreement that this is a moderately important outcome, one that could lengthen or shorten the war but not a critical outcome that would act as a game-changer in the short term**

### Cpt. Rex

> *Rex was going to say that if the access to the Outer Rim routes was matched with a more realistic approach to the number of battles they could fight, then it had achieved something. But **he had a feeling that it wouldn't change a thing, but just spread the Grand Army more thinly.** He had faith in Skywalker, because the man was in there with them, in the thick of it, and he understood the stakes. Rex found his faith was like the atmosphere, getting thinner the higher it went.*

### Kenobi

> *"We need Jabba's backing to fight this war, Anakin. **If we can't use Hutt-controlled routes, we can't fight in the Outer Rim.** It's that simple.*

### Anakin

> ***He*** [Anakin] ***wondered if the Outer Rim routes were really that critical, and if a little more strategic thought could have circumvented the supply-chain problem.*** It was all too late now.

### Sidious / Dooku

> *"Master* [Sidious], *I regret to tell you that the Jedi succeeded, and now have their agreement with the Hutts," Dooku said. "This will make the Outer Rim far harder to hold." "You're aware of the saying about battles and wars, are you not, Count Dooku? You can lose one and yet win the other?" "I am, Master." "Then allow them this victory. **It makes little difference to the overall course of the war. It stretches their forces more thinly. It makes them overconfident. In fact, losing this small skirmish may well be their downfall** when history views the war in years to come." **Dooku had considered that, but as a consolation.***

Answer (score 2):

It might be instructive to look at the war between Vitiate's Sith Empire and the Republic. (Sure, it was 4000 years before, but Hutts is Hutts, right?) In that war, the Hutt Cartel was strictly neutral... except for the Three Families on Quesh who allied with the Republic, and the Cartel forces on Quest who sided with the Empire to stop them, and Karagga who went crazy and tried to take over both sides, and the Hutts on Makeb who threw in with the Republic, but under duress, and then the other Hutts tried to repudiate their agreement...

The point is, the Hutts have a long history of excitingly vicious internal politics. If the Hutts as a whole *had* sided with the Separatists, the Republic could probably have found someone willing to help them on the down-low. (And paid through the nose for it, no doubt.)

In much the same way, during the Yuuzhan Vong war, Hutt Space was simultaneously the home of the Peace Brigade collaborators and the site of major resistance gunrunning operations. The Hutts simply aren't unified enough that the clans taking sides means very much.